# How to get TagWikis along with their corresponding Tags?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Using SEDE I'm trying to get the `TagWiki`s along with their corresponding `Tags`.

This is what I tried (but i get an empty result):

```
select Body,TagName from Posts
inner join PostTags on PostTags.PostId=Posts.Id
inner join Tags on Tags.id=PostTags.TagId
where PostTypeId=5
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68737

Getting the `TagWiki`s alone is no problem, using something like:

```
select top 10 * from Posts
where PostTypeId=5
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68733

But in the `PostTags` table there is no corresponding `PostId` for `Posts` with `PostTypeId=5`, so this query returns an empty result:

```
select * from Posts
inner join PostTags on PostTags.PostId=Posts.Id
where PostTypeId=5
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68711

Is there a way to accomplish this? (or am I just missing something obvious?)

Comment: Uh...huh. Yeah, seems like the necessary data is missing. Not sure if there are supposed to be `PostTags` entries for tag wikis, or if `Tags` is meant to have foreign keys to `Posts` for the excerpt and body...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sam Saffron has revealed the mysteries of the data explorer to me - getting the excerpt and wiki posts associated with a tag is now possible.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73037/getting-tag-wiki-info

Comment: Ah, so you know about the blood sacrifice now then...

Comment: THAT IS MY FAVORITE PART.

Comment: Nice and simple (from our end). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Until the necessary data is added, if you're primarily interested in actually viewing the tag wiki on the site, you *can* [use the `[Post Link]` magic column](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68784) to generate a link that will  take you to the correct tag wiki (whichever tag it happens to belong to).

Comment: That only gives a link which is redirected on the HTTP server to the tag wiki. How can I get the tag name for further use in a query?

Comment: Right, the data required to do so is simply not there at the moment. It's an oversight, but not one that I'm able to directly correct; I'll see what I can do about requesting that it be fixed (assuming your bounty doesn't take care of that).