# Post Link for Tag Info Wiki's display text should be better than "unknown"

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, tag-wiki

The displayed text for a `[Post Link]` where the underlying `Id` corresponds to a Tag/Info Wiki (where the link redirects successfully) is just `"unknown"`.

For example, if you've ever edited a tag wiki: [Suggested edits on my stuff](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/49109/suggested-edits-on-my-stuff).

It would be nice if this could be better identified.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that this wasn't handled properly was that up until recently, there was [no way to know what tag wiki a given post was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130980/how-to-get-tagwikis-along-with-their-corresponding-tags) using the data available.

Since that's changed, I've gone ahead and changed the lookup to account for this case. The new behaviour is controlled by the new `EnableTagWikiTitleLookup` setting, for compatibility with Data Explorer instances running off actual public data dumps, since they lack the information necessary to create the required fields.

As the database behind the public Data Explorer instance *does* have this data, the change should be deployed and enabled in the next revision >  2012.9.7.6.

Comment: It's worth noting that this change actually wasn't picked up because there were some concerns about performance. I'll cycle back around to see if there's another way to handle it.