# Post link is broken for tag wikis

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

I was making a query to tell me which are the shortest (by character length) posts on stack exchange. But I was unaware that [my search includes tag wikis and other posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/255903/shortest-posts-both-questions-and-answers).

[image: data explorer results]

Funny thing is that the link looks like this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135004` and actually leads to *Tag wiki*, despite the `/questions/` part.

Comment: See also: [Post Link for Tag Info Wiki's display text should be better than “unknown”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161063/224428)

Comment: @senshin Seems that literally everything has been said on this meta already :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), because doing the join to get the tag name in the off-chance that your results are looking at tag wikis instead of questions/answers was decided to be prohibitively expensive (mostly for the Stack Overflow tables, where most things are).

That the URL works is a happy coincidence that lets us avoid special-casing this.

You can, of course, [create the link yourself](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) with [a (simplified) query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/255911) like the following:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 'site://tags' + t.TagName + '/info|' + t.TagName + ' tag wiki' AS [Tag Wiki link]
  FROM Posts p
  JOIN Tags t ON p.Id = t.WikiPostId
```

Comment: Any chance user could generate his own nice tag wiki links (somebody coming here from google might need it...)?